# null pointer exception when action class call service method of DAO

Tags: java, spring

I'm getting a null pointer exception when i call a methods of DAO from action.  I have no idea, why I get it. when I check the code it seems right
In Action Class

```
public String getReport() {
    System.out.println("Inside Action");
    ExpenseReportBean bean=new ExpenseReportBean();
    try {
        getexpenseReport=reportdao.getReport();
        return "success";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "success";

    }
}
```

DAO Class:

```
public List<ExpenseReportBean> getReport() {
    System.out.println("Inside DAO");
    sqlQ = "select expense_date,SUM(IF(expense_name='salary',amount,0)) as salary,\n"
                + "SUM(IF(expense_name='rent',amount,0)) as rent\n"
                + "from am_expense\n"
                + "group by DATE_FORMAT(expense_date,'%d-%m-%Y')";

    System.out.println("Inside DAO : SQL =" + sqlQ);
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQ, new RowMapper() {
        public ExpenseReportBean mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
            ExpenseReportBean bean = new ExpenseReportBean();
            bean.setSalary(rs.getString("salary"));
            bean.setRent(rs.getString("rent"));
            bean.setExpense_date(rs.getString("expense_date"));
            System.out.println("Bean= "+rs.getString("rent"));
            return bean;
        }
    });

}
```

XML Files:

```
<action name="getReportAction" class="com.ams.actions.ExpenseReportAction" method="getReport">
            <result name="success" type="json">
                <param name="root">getexpenseReport</param>
            </result>
        </action>

 <bean id="expenseReportdao" class="com.ams.dao.ExpenseReportDao">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>
    </bean>
```

OUTPUT: Getting below ERROR When run this code

```
Execute
Info:   Inside Action
Severe:   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ams.actions.ExpenseReportAction.getReport(ExpenseReportAction.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: can u check the wiring between reportdao object and its bean configuration. I guess the object is null.

Comment: I ckeck it. This is bean configuration:<bean id="expenseReportdao" class="com.ams.dao.ExpenseReportDao">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>
    </bean>

Comment: It is not automatically creating object by using  getter/ setter method of  reportdao instance

Comment: hi Sathish can you paste your entire action class

Comment: hey where are you using bean reference ExpenseReportBean bean=new ExpenseReportBean();? You have created a object and on that object you need to call r8 like bean.getReport();

Comment: Hello pradeep, I am not setting data to bean. I just want to get data from database. getReport is my dao method. I am calling it reportdao.getReport();

Comment: I solve it. It was dependency problem. need to refresh and redeploy.  Thank for quick reply